# Нужно вывести значение элемента массива по его порядковому номерую

Tags: c++

Вот например я хочу ввести число 1 и что бы мне выводило соответствующее значение элемента по индексу, в данном случае 14. Ввожу 2 - выводит 10 и тд.

```html
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
 int n, p, k = n;
 cout << "Введите количество элементов: "; cin >> n;

 double* A = new double[n];

 cout << "Введите " << n << " элементов:\n";
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  cin >> A[i];

 double tmp;
 for (int i = 1, j; i < n; ++i) // цикл проходов, i - номер прохода
 {
  tmp = A[i];
  for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && A[j] < tmp; --j) // поиск места элемента в готовой последовательности 
   A[j + 1] = A[j];    // сдвигаем элемент направо, пока не дошли
  A[j + 1] = tmp; // место найдено, вставить элемент    
 }

 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  cout << A[i] << " ";
 cout << "\n";

 cout << "Введите номер элемента: " << endl;
 delete[]A;
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: После сортировки вставками и выводом элементов циклом for у вас происходит вывод "Введите номер элемента: ", но после этого вывода нет 1) ввода индекса 2) вывод значения элемента по вводимому индексу

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int n, index_for_output;
    cout << "Введите количество элементов: "; 
    cin >> n;

    double* A = new double[n];

    cout << "Введите " << n << " элементов:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> A[i];

    double tmp;
    for (int i = 1, j; i < n; ++i) // цикл проходов, i - номер прохода
    {
        tmp = A[i];
        for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && A[j] < tmp; --j) // поиск места элемента в готовой последовательности 
            A[j + 1] = A[j];    // сдвигаем элемент направо, пока не дошли
        A[j + 1] = tmp; // место найдено, вставить элемент    
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << A[i] << " ";
    cout << "\n";

    cout << "Введите номер элемента: " << endl;
    // ввод индекса для отображения значения
    cin >> index_for_output;
    // вывод значения элемента по индексу
    cout << A[index_for_output] << endl;

    delete[]A;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы задали вопрос о операторе [] он просто выводить значение а[i] (значение в памяти по адресу а со сдвигом I) но вы должны быть уверены что I >= 0, и I < size. Или использовать безопасный метод at(I) в контейнерах stl

```
int main() {

    std::vector<int> v(10, 1);

    int n{0};

    std::cout << "Input n : ";

    while (!(std::cin >> n) || n < 0 || n > static_cast<int>(v.size())) {
        std::cout << "Input error, try again " << std::endl;
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore();
    }

    // вывод через оператор []
    std::cout << v[n] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `index >= 0 && index < size`. не `index > 0`. в C++ индексация с нуля

Comment: @vt-egrov опечатка